# In UINavigationController what is the difference between topViewController, visibleViewController, presentedViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

`UINavigationController` has 3 controllers that all sound very similar to me: `topViewController`, `visibleViewController`, and `presentedViewController`.

Which scenarios do you use each of these controllers in?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

- **topViewController** - last view controller pushed onto the UINavigationController using **UINavigationController's** `pushViewController(_:animated:)` method. Pushes the previous controller out of it's way and replaces it.
- **presentedViewController** - view controller that is presented over top of another (basically it covers up another view controller instead of pushing it out of the way). INSTEAD of **UINavigationController's** `pushViewController(_:animated:)` you use **UIViewController's** `present(_:animated:completion:)` method. *Note: Presented view controllers are also referred to as modal view controllers and can be used WITHOUT a UINavigationController.*
- **visibleViewController** could be the same as topViewController OR presentedViewController. It would be the same as topViewController if you pushed onto the UINavigationController last. It would be the same as the presentedViewController if you presented on a UIViewController last.

Example:

1. Push UIViewController **viewA** onto a UINavigationController.
2. Have **viewA** present UIViewController **viewB** over itself.
3. **viewA** is topViewController.
4. **viewB** is presentedViewController.
5. **viewB** is also visibleViewController.
6. Dismiss modal **viewB**.
7. **viewA** is now topViewController AND visibleViewController. *(There is no presentedViewController.)*
8. Pop **viewA**.
9. **viewA** is no longer visibleViewController OR topViewController.

In general it seems like visibleViewController is more useful since it will tell you what view is currently showing regardless of if it was pushed or presented.

Comment: The other answers had some good insight and I thought I'd add what I've learned since posting this question in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 9):

`presentedViewController` is the current modal presented on screen.
`topViewController` is view controller on top of the navigation stack (see `viewControllers()` method) and `visibleViewController` is the currently displayed view controller on screen (can be either a controller, a modal, a `UINavigationController`, a `UITabbarController`, etc).

Comment: They all sound pretty similar to me.  More information please.

Answer (score 4):

- TopViewController is the topmost VC in the navigation stack. OR the View controller which was pushed last.
- PresentedViewController is the viewController presented modally from the navigationController. It is not part of NaivagationController's horizontal stack, but a viewController presented over it.
- Of these two viewControllers, the one that is visible to the user will be the visibleViewController of the navigationController.