# Unrecognized selector error when pushing segue in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, unrecognized-selector

I have an app which has a sidebar menu (a UITableView) with different rows that are connected separately with the main view controller with a (push) Segue.

Only one of this doesn't work, so when I tap on it I recieve this message:

**** *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainTabBarController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14880ce00'terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

In the SideBarViewController this is the part of the code that causes the crash:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"[segue identifier]: %@",[segue identifier]);

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sync"]) {
    MainViewController *mainViewSync= (MainViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
    mainViewSync.sync = 1;
}}
```

How can I fix That?

Comment: `topViewController` is a `UINavigationController` property, not a `UITabBarController` one. Since I guess that `MainTabBarController` is a `UITabBarController`, that's why you get a crash, since `[segue destinationViewController]` is a `MainTabBarController` and not as you think a `MainViewController`.

Comment: @Larme thank you. Is there a corresponding property for a TabBarViewController? How do I connect them?

Comment: You need to understand what means `topViewController`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395463/in-uinavigationcontroller-what-is-the-difference-between-topviewcontroller-visi Now, your `UITabBarController`, does it have a `UINavigationController` on one of its tab? You want to know which tab is currently selected? And if that's the case, you want to know if there is a modally presented one? The last pushed one through a UINavigationController? It's lacking informations on your architecture...